# Is using extensions in Visual Studios or any application for programming in general a bad practice as a beginner programmer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Of course, it does depend on the application in question. If I am using, for example, a grammar checker to check for mistakes to make the code more readable, I don't think that that is a bad practice (though tell me if it is).

But I am thinking about bigger extensions like Resharper that adds so much, with me not even knowing 95% of what it does.

My big question is: is it a bad practice to use Resharper or similar applications that I mostly don't understand (while the few bits I do understand does help me), while I don't even know how most of the basic Visual Studios application works?

Comment: I dont think there is a common rule for this. This is depends on your own work style and is therefore opinion based.

Comment: Resharper and CodeRush (both of which I use in different environments) are classified as Productivity Enhancement tools. They are designed to make you more productive, and for lots of people they are essential tools. I have paid good money to be able to use a good Unit Test runner and Code Coverage analysers.

Comment: Resharper helps you in your programming by giving advice about how you can do things differently so no, I don't think it is a bad practice to use. Just still need to learn the language and the runtime libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A productivity tool (like R# or others) is supposed to *enhance* your productivity.

That means you should be able to do your job, just do it *faster* (or *cheaper* or whatever other metric you use) with the tool.

If you catch yourself *not being able* to do the job without the tool, because you don't understand what the tool does or cannot replicate it without the tool, that is a problem.

---

Just keep in mind that a tool can vanish for any reason at any time. Your employer may not want to pay for it, may not like it, use a different product or maybe the product does not support your preferred environment anymore or simply has bugs. You cannot tell an employer that you *cannot* do something because a $100 tool broke when you are paid $100K. It's acceptable that you take longer, but not that you have to give up.

Comment: do you mean Resharper when you say R#? I read R# as the library that allows R to be used in C#? I have never seen resharper refered to like that

Comment: @StevenWood Ah yes, sorry for the confusion, that's their logo if you look at their [page](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Comment: huh, yeah, ive been using it for years, but havent actually seen the logo for a long time haha. anyway +1 for the "if you cant perform an action without the tool thats a problem"